# Docker check if container running is ARM or Intel

Tags: docker

Is there some way to check if a running image is ARM or Intel on Docker?

I am running the official Postgres docker image and I wondering if it is ARM or Intel

Comment: Well what type of CPU do you have?

Comment: Apple MacBook m1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inspect the image with `docker image inspect $image_name` and the following lines will be included in the output:

```
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
```

Or you can format the inspect output:

```
$ docker image inspect busybox --format '{{ .Os }}/{{ .Architecture }}'
linux/amd64
```

This is metadata on the image, and doesn't guarantee that the binaries contained within haven't been compiled for a different architecture. On the same filesystem, you can have binaries compiled for lots of architectures (I do this all the time when cross compiling binaries to release for different architectures). Those binaries are what's really important when determining the platform. However, for a properly built image, that isn't an issue and the platform definition in the image is what you're looking for.